# Set priority of process in Windows 10 - access denied

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, administrator, task-manager

In Windows 10 after loading Task Manager you have to click the Details tab to see the processes, not the Processes tab, but now when I right-click a process, click *Set priority* and choose low, I get an `Access Denied` error.

(**note**: this is the Malware Bytes process)

I've tried running Task Manager as administrator, but it doesn't work.

How to fix access denied problem?

Comment: Which process are you trying to affect?

Comment: malware bytes .

Comment: hmm, now that you mention it, I tried setting lower priority for chrome, and it worked

Comment: i guess it's an antivirus so it doesn't like letting anything touch their processes

Comment: why the thumbs down? it's an excellent question.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but it was probably for not specifying which process. Thanks for editing to include that.

Comment: Andrew is correct. The access control list on the process doesn't permit its priority to be changed. Running as "Administrator" doesn't give you access to everything - in fact, an ACL can be set to _deny_ access to Administrator, or to members of the Administrators group, etc. Or to everyone, for that matter.

Comment: The case is probably is with ownership on MalwareBytes executables. If you stop process, take ownership to some of your administrators account and add yourself in security tab  with full access then you would be able to manage it via task manager

Comment: Do you have the malwarebytes Self Protection module enabled? https://support.malwarebytes.com/customer/portal/articles/1834890-what-is-the-self-protection-module-and-why-should-i-enable-it-?b_id=6438

Comment: Alex: The security attributes of the executable file doesn't control access to the running process. "change priority" isn't even one of the methods that apply to files.